# VS Code C++ program does not display any output while debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Take a simple C++ file like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);

    cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Set breakpoint at `return 0`. Setup this launch config:

```
{
    "name": "g++ build and debug active file",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ],
    "preLaunchTask": "g++ build active file",
    "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
 }
```

Goto debug tab in left sidebar and click green run button.

**Expected situation:** I can see `Hello World` somewhere.
**Actual situation:** I can**not** see `Hello World` anywhere.

**Right side tabs:**

- **Output**: empty
- **Problems**: empty
- **Terminal 1**: `cppdbg: temp` empty
- **Terminal 2**: `Task - g++ build active file` [content](https://pastebin.com/F7fxEiU8)
- **Debug console**: [content](https://pastebin.com/6fM5BiPg)

How to fix this?

---

**Setup**: VS Code 1.33.1 (Official Snap build) on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Probably by adding a newline to the string. The output may be buffered.

Comment: `cout << "Hello World\n";` or even better `cout << "Hello World" << endl;`. `endl` outputs a newline and flushes the stream.

Comment: Thanks, putting an `endl` worked (`\n` didn't), but that is very weird behavior from VSCode.

Comment: It's not vs codes behaviour, your operating system buffers output before printing to the console, this is entirely normal and fairly universal across all platforms

Comment: @john there seems to be recent contra information to using `std::endl`, see [ACCU Overload 149 - Don't Use `std::endl`](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload149.pdf). I don't think it is a showstopper either way, but curios about your comment.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm assuming that the OPs problem is because he hasn't flushed the stream. The article suggests using an explicit `flush` instead of `endl` if flushing is required. That's just a stylistic concern. Like you, I don't see it as a big deal either way,

Comment: @GaurangTandon Can you tell me where do you see the output of `cout` bcz. I cannot see it anywhere?

Comment: @Jos You should find it in the Integrated Terminal of vscode or your own external console, depending on your `"externalConsole"` setting in launch.json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to helpful comments above, also I'll quote [Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5494370/alan-birtles):

> It's not vs codes behaviour, your operating system buffers output before printing to the console, this is entirely normal and fairly universal across all platforms

Thus I needed to add an extra `std::endl` to my `std::cout` statement.